# overflow: hidden not working when positioned absolutely in webkit browsers( please help)

Tags: overflow, hidden, element

If you look at this example in a webkit browser, chrome, safari

http://freemotive.co.uk/dev/exp2.html

the overflow: hidden set on the span element doesn't seem to work when positioned absolutely.

The general idea is that the span element will hide the image within a circle using border radius.

i've read that it is a bug within webkit, however i'm wondering if there is a work around to solve the issue?

i've played with ideas, but nothing has worked yet.

hope some of you can help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're basically trying to "frame" the image within a circle by using a span with border-radius and overflow:hidden... why not try applying the border-radius to the image element itself?

Comment: if you look at the desired outcome in firefox you'll see that the span expands on hover revealing slightly more of the image below, applying this on the img will expand the img making it pixelated.

Comment: ok so i worked it out, but i'm not entirely sure why it works this way and not the other, 

if you apply the img through css inline with  

`style="background-image: url(../image/);"`

this fixes the overflow hidden problem on positioned elements in chrome and safari.

hope this helps anyone else that comes across the same issue.